# Правильная десериализация ответа из сети

Tags: java, архитектура

Суть вопроса вот в чем, нужно получать данные от АПИшки.
Набор данных разный для каждого метода АПИ + есть отдельный ответ с ошибками на случай если запрос был составлен не корректно.

Можно ли сделать один класс для работы с разными наборами данных?

Варианты ответа 1

```
{
  "result": {
    "Clients": [
      {
        "AccountQuality": 0.1,
        "Archived": "( YES | NO )",
        "ClientId": 1,
        "Login": "(string)",
        "Notification": {
          "Lang": "RU",
          "SmsPhoneNumber": "(string)",
          "Email": "(string)",
          "EmailSubscriptions": [
            {
              "Option": "RECEIVE_RECOMMENDATIONS",
              "Value": "( YES | NO )"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Варианты ответа 2

```
{
  "result": {
    "Services": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "(string)",
        "StartDate": "(string)",
        "StatusClarification": "(string)",
        "SourceId": "(long)",
        "Currency": "USD",
        "RepresentedBy": {
          "Manager": "(string)",
          "Agency": "(string)"
        },
        "EndDate": "(string)",
        "BlockedIps": {
          "Items": [
            "(string)"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`p.s. вариантов ответа на деле больше чем 2`

Вопрос относится больше к архитектуре, нежели к реализации.
Не могу придумать как лучше сделать.

Написать pojo для каждого ответа и обернуть их в один большой класс response? Или оставить по отдельности? Или сделать просто один большой класс с набором полей для каждого ответа?

Или на такие случаи мб есть какой-то паттерн?

Поделитесь опытом, кто как как строит подобные моменты в своем коде :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Однозначного ответа на любой подобный вопрос нет, у вас всегда tradeoff и никто кроме Вас не знает требования предоставляемые к программе, которую вы разрабатываете.

Если вам надо быстро или на один раз - глупо тратить время на архитектуру.

А вот если это задел чего-то грандиозного и вы много раз будете это ещё раз менять - конечно есть смысл отделить мух от котлет.

Но опять же, если каждый раз API кардинально меняется, вы все равно потратите лишнее время на изобретения.

Потом ещё, кто будет поддерживать этот код? Подумайте о нем тоже.

Если это вы же только в будущем, тогда вы скорее всего разберётесь с любой своей же концепцией, а вот если это будет другой человек, менее одаренный чем вы, ему будет проще если код будет проще.

Это я все к тому, что любое усложнение должно быть оправдано больше, чем "мне так захотелось" или "мне сказали/я читал что так правильно"

PS, слегка сумбурно и не ругайте за ошибки, писано с телефона, буду у монитора поправлю. :)

Comment: Спасибо, я вас понял :)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд один общий класс нарушает первый [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) принцип. Принцип единственной ответственности гласит, что каждая отдельная сущность должна выполнять свою строго опеределенную работу.
Нарушая этот принцип вы рискуете наткнуться на сложность добаления изменений в ваш код. Когда вы будете менять,обновлять или дополнять один ответ, вы неявно будете затрагивать и другие. Это потенциальный источник ошибок. Кроме того, такой код сложнее читать. На мой вгзляд, тут определенно необходимо разносить ответы по классам.

Comment: даже если этот код никто ни разу больше не будет читать?)

Comment: Простите, а зачем он пишется тогда?) Если его никто никогда не будет читать, то вопрос вообще теряет смысл. Тогда такое приложение можно воспринимать как черный ящик, который идеально работает и совершенно не важно, что внутри. Понятное дело, что в реальном мире в настоящих проектах такого не встречается. :)

Comment: для того чтобы скомпилировать в программу и использовать её, никогда не возвращаясь к её переделкам